# jackson do not deserialize child list object

Tags: java, json, mongodb, jackson

I receive the following JSON:

```
{"firstName":"charle","lastName":"charly","books":[{"title":"navle"}]}
```

And i try to parse it into this Jackson object:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {

  @Id @ObjectId
  private String _id;

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  List<Book> books; 
// getters/setters ..
}
```

The problem is that the Object "Person" that i get have always an empty list of books !

What i'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribut "title" of the book should be public or you must annotate his getter like this:

```
@JsonProperty("title")
public String getTitle() {
   return title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the list of books public, Jackson will serialize only "visible" properties.
Plus Book properties must be public.

```
public List<Book> books;
```

or better create a getter

```
@JsonProperty("books")
public List<Books> getBooks() {
   return books;
}
```

Comment: Thx for your hint. It works when i set the attribute "title" to public instead of private. The annotation works also well